# Xcode test coverage for Swift APIs that don't have explicit body

Tags: swift, xcode, code-coverage

I'm looking for a way to get test coverage for the Swift APIs that don't have explicit implementations (e.g., properties, enum cases, type names, protocols, etc). Specifically, to understand whether they are used during execution or not.

It looks like Xcode 14 skips all mentioned Swift constructs in the coverage report both in Xcode UI and in the .xccov file produced from .xcresult.

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: You mean you want to ensure there's no dead code in your codebase? The fact that a property is accessed doesn't really mean that the property is useful - adding property or even type accesses to test coverage would be pretty pointless.

Comment: The original problem was to find coverage for all public APIs in a distributed library. To know that all APIs are tested. Obviously, with the way test coverage works, it's not a strict check, as we don't know if it's used in the test code or in the implementation code and if it's asserted or not. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77230511/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.